# What is the best software to manage dupes and clean up data in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mp3

I know there are a lot of paid options but was wondering what folks have found to be the best.  Following tasks would be the minimum requirement:

- merging dupes
- identifying dupes with case difference
- identifying dupes with pluralisation difference
- identifying dupes with spelling probs
- identifying dupes where collaborating artists are cited differently
- identifying when 2 tracks are not dupes because track lengths are different
- getting album art where it is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use itunes in built find duplicates then manually trawl the list. Be careful though as itunes matches tracks on tags ( name ) thus a 7min version of a track can be match to a 3min version of a track with the same title.

<strike>I do not know of an application that can reliably find imagines for missing album work.</strike>
Completely forgot about [Tuneup](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/) which can clean up and mp3's and find missing imagines. Has some very good review although I have yet to use :)

Comment: @i-moan - thanks, this is a great piece of software!

Answer (score 1):

iTunes has a "show duplicates" menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the available options, but if you're feeling adventurous, you can try using some AppleScript to at least help identify duplicates (if not delete them).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: [GimmeSomeTune](http://www.eternalstorms.at/gimmesometune/index.html) can do missing artwork, and does it well.

Comment: Extra info: GimmeSomeTune is a free iTunes add on. Only negative I can think of is that it sometimes makes the currently playing song skip if it needs to write info to the mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the COM library form the Apple site and wrote a Macro in Excel to do some simple Soundex Matching on tracks, this sorted out my library to some extent. I belive you can do something similar on a Mac
(I then switched to a Zune which made the whole task much simpler)